# Final render doesn't look the same as it does in the preview (2.8)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to make a synthwave landscape sort of thing, but when I try to render it, all the textures look wrong. The textures look correct in preview mode:[image]

But when I render it:
[image]

How do I fix this? I'm using Eevee.
EDIT: Here are my render settings:
[image]

Everything except for these 3 settings is turned off. I've tried to turn them off, but to no avail.

Comment: You made need to post your shader node set up and a shot of your render settings, what is the material setting like on your wireframe modifier?

Comment: As @Chris said, you might have done something in the materials of the meshes. post a screenshot of shading tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to solve that issue... but you can use this.

Goto-> View-> Viewport render.

but to get the render correct. you need to hide all those cursor, grid, arrows etc.,
Hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: This took a while for my computer to handle, but it worked! Thanks, man.

Comment: @Taco so accept the answer and give an upvote

Answer (score 0):

If you are using images for creating materials make sure you did not delete the images. I believe if you change an image textures directory or delete it from your computer it will mess up in Blender.

Comment: I'm not using any images :/